# IdentityServer4 throws 500 internal server error when using Authorize attribute on API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api, identityserver4, http-status-code-500

I have been trying to figure this out all weekend, but can't seem to get it to work. Please help.

I have setup IdentityServer 4, an MVC application and an API.
I get an access token after login, but when I try to access the API it throws 500 internal server error (if I have an Authorize attribute)

**this is my identityserver config file:**

```
public static IEnumerable<IdentityResource> IdentityResources =>
          new IdentityResource[]
          {
        new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
        new IdentityResources.Profile(),
          };

public static IEnumerable<ApiScope> ApiScopes =>
    new ApiScope[]
    {
        new ApiScope("api1", "my API")
    };


public static IEnumerable<Client> Clients =>
    new Client[]
    {

        new Client
        {
            ClientId = "mvc",
            ClientSecrets = { new Secret("secret".Sha256()) },

            AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,

            RedirectUris = { "https://localhost:5002/signin-oidc" },
            //FrontChannelLogoutUri = "https://localhost:5002/signout-oidc",
            PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "https://localhost:5002/signout-callback-oidc" },

            AllowOfflineAccess = true,
            AllowedScopes = new List<string>
            {
                IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                "api1" 
            }
        }
    };
```

**This is the identityServer startup class:**

```
public IWebHostEnvironment Environment { get; }
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public Startup(IWebHostEnvironment environment, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Environment = environment;
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllersWithViews();


        if (System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT") == "Production")
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyDbConnection")));
        else
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        var builder = services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
        {
            options.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
            options.Events.RaiseInformationEvents = true;
            options.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
            options.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;

            // see https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/resources.html
            options.EmitStaticAudienceClaim = true;
        })
            .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.IdentityResources)
            .AddInMemoryApiScopes(Config.ApiScopes)
            .AddInMemoryClients(Config.Clients)
            .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>();

        // not recommended for production - you need to store your key material somewhere secure
        builder.AddDeveloperSigningCredential();

        services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddGoogle(options =>
            {
                options.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;

               
                options.ClientId = "xxx.apps.googleusercontent.com";
                options.ClientSecret = "xxx";

                options.ReturnUrlParameter = "https://xxx.azurewebsites.net/signin-google";
            }).AddFacebook(facebookOptions => 
            {
                facebookOptions.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;
                facebookOptions.ClientId = "xxx";
                facebookOptions.ClientSecret = "xxx";
                facebookOptions.ReturnUrlParameter = "https://xxx.azurewebsites.net/signin-facebook";
            });

    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        if (Environment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseIdentityServer();

        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
        });
    }
```

**This is my API startup class:**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.Configuration;

namespace SF.API
{
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }
    public IConfiguration Configuration
    {
        get;
    }
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers();

        // accepts any access token issued by identity server
        services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
            .AddJwtBearer("Bearer", options =>
            {
                options.Authority = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IdentityServerAddress"];
                
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateAudience = false
                };

            });

        // adds an authorization policy to make sure the token is for scope 'api1'
        //services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        //{
        //    options.AddPolicy("ApiScope", policy =>
        //    {
        //        policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
        //        policy.RequireClaim("scope", "api1");
        //    });
        //});
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
       
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"); 
           
        });
        app.UseStaticFiles();

    }
}
```

}

**this is the Controller class:**

```
[Route("identity")]
[Authorize]
public class IdentityController : ControllerBase
{
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        return new JsonResult(from c in User.Claims select new { c.Type, c.Value });
    }
    [Route("/Test")]
    public IActionResult Test()
    {
        return new JsonResult(from c in User.Claims select new { c.Type, c.Value });
    }
}
```

**This is the MVC application startup class:**

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllersWithViews();

        JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultMapInboundClaims = false;

        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
        })
        .AddCookie("Cookies")
        .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
        {
            

            options.Authority = "https://xxx.azurewebsites.net";
            options.ClientId = "mvc";
            options.ClientSecret = "secret";
            options.ResponseType = "code";

            options.SaveTokens = true;
            options.Scope.Add("api1");
            options.Scope.Add("offline_access");
        });
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute()
                .RequireAuthorization();
        });
    }
```

This is how I call the API:

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> CallApi()
    {
        var accessToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");

        var client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
        var content = await client.GetStringAsync("https://localhost:6001/Test");
        ViewBag.Json = JArray.Parse(content).ToString();
        
        return View("json");
    }
```

My access token looks like this:

```
"eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IkExNDYxOUUzOTAwNjM5ODA2NUU4RkUwQjJFMkU1RThFIiwidHlwIjoiYXQrand0In0.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.Grcu-dbrLy6LHHxsW2FJsSIhmwQBEl1jQ2LRvJhBFzZ8j0HAqk129Q8JncJFSFBjQkEls8xBFN-OxyvhJ5o7dmgpkgYENbfjl7jC04yhvSh_MzLqG2h_mme1mwsC3xzuKbQR1yczei-j92WUMeP-CvzUtr2vbJd2lJv0YvpJvykGF4BbKrQMPLPZnlLFRkPm5LcdFfUsrHrCz3R0JZ7tpVSwGMjGMlDHlAMAR04Fzf6YQhbKUEydNdTIWFP2akyBoWuRwAvTXbOA8vm9GZpeTbo8S4At5X7RhOR_J-zIjk1QWKhqN9kVMnMLXpO_NmZ6iQ66pcnT0G75rtFEfFtISQ"
```

Is there anything wrong with how I access the token? I can't see the scopes for example?

What else could be wrong?

**Update: I added app.UseAuthorization() in the API.Startup class. Then I got 401 Unauthroized instead

Comment: bit confused, you get an error in IdentityServer when you try to access the API using the received access token?  Are they in the same service instance(same project?)

Comment: @ToreNestenius no the API is one project and the identityserver is another one!

Comment: Hi, for reference [the following code works](https://github.com/PieterjanDeClippel/SSO), but sadly i'm not home so can't verify your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem with the API is that it lacks

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

In the API startup class.

To debug the API in ASP.NET Core, you can try to set the log level top debug or trace, like this in appsetttings:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication": "Trace",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization": "Trace"
    }
  }
}
```

You should check inside the access token header:

```
{
  "alg": "RS256",
  "kid": "A14619E39006398065E8FE0B2E2E5E8E",
  "typ": "at+jwt"
}
```

The kid key identifier must be present in the JWKS endpoint.

Comment: The comments seem to have been deleted. My latest error is:  Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenSignatureKeyNotFoundException and kid: '[PII is hidden.

Comment: That is wierd that we comments was deleted? strange! see my updated answer.

Comment: I looked and it looks exactly like what you posted above!

Comment: What does the API logs say when the token arrives?

Comment: info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler[1]
      Failed to validate the token.
      Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenSignatureKeyNotFoundException: IDX10501: Signature validation failed. Unable to match key:
kid

Bearer was not authenticated. Failure message: IDX10501: Signature validation failed. Unable to match key:
kid

Comment: Hej! Is your token issued by the same instance of IdentityServer that your API talks to?

Comment: Hej! I think so? I am not sure

Comment: It can be one source of trouble, so you need to make sure that all services in the system talks to the same instance of IdentityServer. Same   options.Authority = "https://xxx.azurewebsites.net";

Comment: I changed from retrieving the value from appsettings to a hard coded value, and that did the trick! Forever grateful for your patience and help, thank you thank you!

Comment: Häftigt! Glad I could solve your problem :-)

Comment: Hej! Did you solve it?